# Emacs org-mode latex export doesnt export bibliography

Tags: emacs, latex, export, org-mode, bibtex

I tried to export a document with orgmode to a pdf. Unfortunately it doesnt export the citations. I make a minimal example of and export it. Same Problem. So maybe i think there is a Problem with the \printbibliography.

**org file**

```
# Latexheader

#+LATEX_HEADER: \documentclass[12pt]{article}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[a4paper, left=4cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm,margin=2cm]{geometry}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{biblatex}


# Bibliography

#+bibliography: ../lit.bib
#+cite_export: csl <PATH>/ieee.csl

# Document

* Heading

Test [cite:@all]

#+print_bibliography:
```

**lit.bib**

```
@inproceedings{all,
  title={papertitle},
  author={paperauthor},
  booktitle={PAPER3000},
  year={2002}
}
```

**tex file**

```
% Created 2022-09-20 Di 20:59
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{minted}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=4cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\author{xdobx}
\date{\today}
\title{}
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={xdobx},
 pdftitle={},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 28.1 (Org mode 9.5.2)}, 
 pdflang={English}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\citeprocitem}[2]{\hyper@linkstart{cite}{citeproc_bib_item_#1}#2\hyper@linkend}
\makeatother

\usepackage[notquote]{hanging}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\section{Heading}
\label{sec:org89209e9}

Test TEST [1]

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output is unsatisfying.

[PDF without bibliography](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjuFw.png)

I tried different ways:

- wrap \printbibliography in a #+begin_latex/#+end_latex block.
- install citeproc-org: but this only brought more errors
- add biblatex with `#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{biblatex}` as @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz suggest
  : correct export of header, but no difference in .pdf

How can i get a nice IEEE-Style formatted bibliography at the end of my document?

**Edit I**

- rewrite `\printbibliography` to `#+print_bibliography:` and it works in the minimal example, if i tried it at the original document it only works if i don't use `#+cite_export: csl <PATH>/ieee.csl`.
  If i use it, i get a error: `unknown bibliography extension: nil`

**Edit II**

- the rewrite from Edit I works, i just forget a `#+BIBLIOGRAPHY: here` from citeproc-org somewhere in the big file.

Comment: No idea about org-mode, but `\printbibliography` is a biblatex macro, so you'll need to load the biblatex package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct solution is to load \biblatex with
 `#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{biblatex}` and insert bibliography with`#+print_bibliography:` where you want. Correct minimal example .org :

```
# Latexheader

#+LATEX_HEADER: \documentclass[12pt]{article}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[a4paper, left=4cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm,margin=2cm]{geometry}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{biblatex}


# Bibliography

#+bibliography: ../lit.bib
#+cite_export: csl <PATH>/ieee.csl

# Document

* Heading

Test [cite:@all]

#+print_bibliography:
```